# C# winforms disable webview from dragging/sliding out element to desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, webview

as the title say, I would like to disable client from dragging or sliding out an element into a c# winforms webview to the desktop.
This will avoid the client from making an icon on desktop to the current page link.

Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: Is the Drag Source (from where dragging begins) part of the C# WinForms app? If so you can disable the DoDragDrop even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a piece of JS code into the page:

```
document.ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

Comment: that solved my problem, thanks a lot for your answer!